# Primefaces dialog is blank when dynamic is set to true

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay

I am trying to convert my dialogues to lazy load to speed up page load time but when I set dialog attribute dynamic to true it shows nothing but just a blank dialog I have used the exact code provided on Primefaces showcase but it does not even show a simple p:outputext

Environment :
jdk : 1.7
liferay : 6.2
primefaces : 5.3
ManagedBeanScope : Session

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Dialog" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" type="button" />
<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" dynamic="true">
   <h:outputText value="This content is loaded lazy." />
</p:dialog>
```

My current page load time is a lot because of dialog

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnE2O.png)

Edit :

This tag is working when the XHTML file is directly included in the ftl file of the Liferay theme but not in portlets.

Comment: Current PrimeFaces showcase is for version 7. Did you check the showcase (and/or documentation) for 5.3?

Comment: I checked the documentation and yes the dynamic attribute is supported in 5.3

Comment: But can you USE it like you call it from the button (I mean with the 'type="button" ? And did you check network traffic? Does it make a call to the server? Or are there any javascript errors that prevent that?

Comment: yes the dialog open on button click but it does not show the outputtext in it as written in the code above, I have also attached a screenshot of the dialog now

Comment: Sorry, yes that it shows is logical, but is it also supposed to work like this (a type="button" normally does not do an ajax, so the dialog must do this. So you MUST see a network call then. Did you check that? And the browser console? Any errors? or other info?

Comment: and did you try a very small [mcve] outside liferay? Does it work there?

Comment: no server or browser error is produced during the dialog call and I tried it with and without ajax

Comment: But was there network traffic when pressing the button? Or is that what you mean by 'the dialog call'?.... And explicit `ajax=true` on a `type="button"` is useless.

Comment: yes there was a network call, I think this has to do something with the scope of the bean but there is no network call in Primefaces showcase and also no bean is used

Comment: There is in the current showcase a network call on the first button click when the dialog is shown for the first time. In subsequent clicks there is not. And regarding the bean, I have no clue what you mean. It is not different from your case (also no bean)

Comment: yes you are right there is

Comment: so it is working but it is weird, it only works if I put it in the header of my application

Comment: No idea what you mean by this... is it an `h:head`?. Using correct terminology is very important.

Comment: Can youy try, just for this issue, with PrimeFaces 6.3 or even 7.0

Comment: I cannot update my Primefaces version it conflicts with Liferay version